# Embedded youtube video loading but not playing

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, shopify

I'm developing a Shopify website and I'd like to embed a Yt video. I choose to make it myself.

Following the Youtube API and related (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=it#Getting_Started) I managed to basically copy and paste the following code:

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '{{ section.settings.id }}'
    });
  }
</script>
```

of course {{ section.settings.id }} is working properly and in fact the video player loads, but when pressed to play video gets me "There was an error. Try later." thing. So I thought that maybe it's because the website is password protected, but then I tried with a live website (Tryit Editor) and it didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

EDIT: Here's the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kb06t7rh/

Comment: you need to provide a working demo for better assistance.

Comment: @Onkar done, please have a look

Comment: Opening the fiddle link, everything works for me

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm in chrome, and it doesn't work for me... any thoughts?

Comment: I've tried it in the latest Firefox version, and the latest Chrome version, and in both browsers, I could start the video

Comment: @BenjaminCarafa in fiddle link all is working fine also on my side, no issue with the latest version of chrome

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback, I tried on a different computer and it works fine... I'll try to check why it doesn't work on mine

Comment: @might be an outdated version or some extensions installed over it like Adblock that make a conflict with it.

Comment: Okay, so I tried it the following day and it just simply worked. Idk what could be the issue but nothing has changed relative to chrome or other extensions since when it didn't work. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '{{ section.settings.video_url.id }}'
    });
  }
</script>
```

Shopify schema for video option

```
{
    "type": "video_url",
    "id": "video_url",
    "label": "video_url",
    "accept": ["youtube"]
}
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect first of all from a syntax perspective (Schema) and it doesn't answer my question: the video loads but why doesn't it play?

Comment: Do you want to autopay on page load?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it